# Topology - Derived Sets

Tags: general-topology

A quick question to clarify properties of derived sets:

Suppose $X$ is a topological space. If $A$ and $B$ are any two subsets of $X$, show that it is not true in general that $\overline{A \cap  B} = \overline{A} \cap \overline{B}$.

Any thoughts? I'd really appreciate an explanation of the intuition behind this. Also, I'm pretty new--would anyone be able to tell me how to make intersection and union symbols?

Comment: Any two disjoint open sets whose boundaries meet will do. You can visualize simple examples in $\mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{R}^2$, and $\mathbb{R}^3$ using open balls.

Answer (score 3):

Can you think of two sets that are disjoint, but whose closures are not? **Hint**: Can you think of a non-closed set and a point outside it that lies in its closure?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one thing that might point you in the right direction: Note that $\mathbb{Q} \subset \mathbb{R}$, and $\overline{\mathbb{Q}} = \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Also, I don't know why the text appeared as me noting compliments of A and B--please disregard that in case that shapes your answers.

Answer (score 0):

I thought of this one.

Take the circle $S^{1}$ and the open disk $D$, both of the same radius, in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$. Then, $\rm{Cl}(S^{1})=S^{1}$ and $\rm{Cl}\left(D\right)$ is the closed disk. Therefore, since $S^{1}\cap D=\varnothing$ and $S^{1}\cap\rm{Cl}\left(D\right)=S^{1}$, we have $\rm{Cl}\left(S^{1}\cap D\right)=\rm{Cl}\left(\varnothing\right)=\varnothing\neq S^{1}=S^{1}\cap\rm{Cl}\left(D\right)=\rm{Cl}(S^{1})\cap\rm{Cl}\left(D\right)$.

There are probably more elegant examples, but this is what came to mind off hand.